# How to combine records in R with Fuzzy Comparison and summarise a value

Tags: r, group-by, bigdata, fuzzy-comparison

I'm trying to condense a data set 10m+ records where I need to group by names and city, and summarise their value. I've done this to an extent with group_by() but some names are misspelled a little and I need to group these further. I read up on using distance measure but don't know how to apply it here while grouping and not overwriting the value, bearing in mind it is a huge data set to compare.

Reproducable example:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(c("MARY", "MARY MS","JOHN L L MR","JOHN L MR","MURPHY","MURPHY","JONES","JONES","WEST ROXBURY","WEST ROXBURY","LACKAWANNA","LACKAWANNA","1","1","2","1"),ncol=4,dimnames=list(seq(1:4),c("firstName","lastName","City","contributions"))))
```

Small example of what it currently looks like

```
    firstName   lastName     City         contributions
1   MARY        MURPHY       WEST ROXBURY   1
2   MARY MS     MURPHY       WEST ROXBURY   1
3   JOHN L L MR JONES        LACKAWANNA     2
4   JOHN L MR   JONES        LACKAWANNA     1
```

What I want it to look like:

```
    firstName   lastName     City         contributions
1   MARY        MURPHY       WEST ROXBURY   2
2   JOHN L MR   JONES        LACKAWANNA     3
```

I've tried:

```
  group_by(firstName,lastName,City) %>%
  summarise(contributions = sum(contributions))
```

Is there a solution that is similar to group_by() but uses a fuzzy match (say wrong by up to 2 characters)

Comment: Please show a small reproudcible example with expected output

Comment: Updated with example and expected output

Comment: look up `agrep` or `agrepl`

Comment: Yea using agrep at the minute but not sure I'm using it right I'm looping over each record comparing it with the last and it takes hours to complete this dataset.